# How to slice part of string from the middle to the end using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have string like this:

```
река Марица - гр. Първомай + Maritsa - 132543 - HPoint-Water level
```

I want to get only `Maritsa - 132543 - HPoint-Water level` with javascript.

For now I get the string and console log all string, but I need to cut the cyrillic string and `-` before `Maritsa`.
The problem is that the loaded names are always different. Is there a way to delete everything before the + including it and show everything after the +

[image]

Comment: why not take directly?

Comment: Because this data is loaded in a dropdown and from the selected value I want to take only that part that I need to be submitted as a parameter in another request.

Comment: you need some definition. the length does not work, it returns `'tsa - 132543 - HPoint-Water level'`

Comment: I update my question, can you check please :)

Comment: so, `str.split('+')[1]`?

Comment: `str.split('+').pop().trim()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace the unwanted part.

```js
const s = 'река Марица - гр. Първомай + Maritsa - 132543 - HPoint-Water level';

console.log(s.replace(/.*\+\s?/, ''));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can combine `String.prototype.indexOf` (which returns the first occurence of a char) and `Array.prototype.slice` (to return the string only after a certain index, here after the + and the space after it) :

```js
const name = 'река Марица - гр. Първомай + Maritsa - 132543 - HPoint-Water level'

const cutString = string => string.slice(string.indexOf('+') + 2)
//           add 2 to also remove the + and the space after it ^ 

console.log(`"${ cutString(name) }"`)
```

Hope it helped you !